# How to open networks over 30.000 nodes in Gephi

Tags: windows, bigdata, ram, gephi

I am running Gephi 0.9.2 in Windows 10 (64x, 8Gb RAM) with normal performance in networks under 30.000 nodes. When I try with bigger datasets the program just crashes. Sometimes it happens when the program just has been open; others it happens when applying ForceAtlas2.

I tried to upload the limit of RAM memory usage in gephi.conf from 1400m to many different values but when I do that the program cannot be opened.

Answer (score 2):

It might well be that 8Gb of RAM is insufficient to run a network of 30,000 nodes. Especially if your nodes and / or edges have attributes.
What you can do is:

- create a stripped version of your network where nodes and edges have no attributes. You can do that by navigating to the Data laboratory and deleting the columns of your attributes.

or

- test your network on a laptop with 16Gb of RAM (not easy, I know) and see if that makes any difference.